# Laravel Authentication returning incorrect user id

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, registration

Basically auth()->user() should return user with id 3 (the user I'm logged in as), but instead returns the user with the previous id (id - 1)

Even stranger is the fact that in the app.blade file, the auth()->user() returns the correct user, but in the rest of the application, even through getting the user via API call retrieves the previous user, and this occurs only after registration.

When I log out and log in, the user id is correct all around.

I'm using Auth::routes() in my web.php so I it's something related to that, given that the database IDs are all correct and so is the login.

Comment: `When I log in and log out, the user id is correct all around.` - so in which cases is the user ID not correct?

Comment: @thefallen when I register as a new user, the new registered user is logged in and and the application "thinks" that said user is actually user with id (userId -1)

Comment: Can you add some code where you think the problem might be? Like registration controller, signing in, something related to the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was difficult figuring out where the problem was coming from, but I finally confirmed that it was a problem between register with session and login with api.

I solved it re-doing the register all over again but in api this time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).